# web.config redirect multiple domains to one

Tags: web-config

Hi  i am trying to redirect my domain aliases to one domain.

I currently have this rule

```
<rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true"
        pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}"
      appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

It works perfect when the alias doesnt have the www in front.. how do i say redirect all that is not equal to this domain

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try it. I'm not sure if it works or not, I'm not great in this subject but this has been sitting here for 4 months unanswered, so I thought I'd give it a wollop.

```
<rule name="Rewrite domain requests" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.mydomain.com/url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

It's the pattern I'm unsure of. I ***think*** this says, match anything in the URL, whether with or without www, and any possible domain extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add one rule for each domain. It keeps query string too:

Lloyd Zhang : http://forums.iis.net/t/1185885.aspx

```
<rule name="Domain Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}mydomainalias.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mydomain\.com" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. 
You have to negate the main domain to avoid a redirect loop.

```
<rule name="Rewrite domain requests" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```